# Links outside of Navbar in different resolutions

Tags: html, css

I'm  making a website and I'm trying to figure out why my navigation links go past the nav bar area on different resolutions.  I've looked up answers and i found to use % on your positions and widths.  But this is still a reoccuring problem.  Heres my code.

HTML

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Template Two</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="visual.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul id="navGroup">
                <li class="navList"><a href="" id="home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navList"><a href="" id="products">Products</a></li>
                <li class="navList"><a href="" id="about">About</a></li>
                <li class="navList"><a href="" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>





#container{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#cc9752;
    float:left;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#cc9752,#291f00);
}

#header{
    position:relative;
    top:1%;
    width:98%;
    height:20%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#0f3b5f;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px;
}

#navigation{
    position:relative;
    top:1%;
    width:98%;
    height:10%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#e5dbcf;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 20px;
    border-top: 4px ridge #0f3b5f;
    overflow:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#navGroup{
    position:relative;
    left:0%;
    top:10%;
}
.navList{
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    }

#home,#products,#about,#contact{
   color:brown;
   text-decoration:none;
   border-right:1px solid grey;
   position:relative;
   padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#contact{
    position:relative;
    left:60%;
}
#about{
    position:relative;
    left:40%;
}
#products{
    position:relative;
    left:20%;
}
#home{
    position:relative;
    left:5%;
}
#center{}
#footer{}
```

Comment: Can you create a http://jsFiddle.net/ ?

Comment: It would be great to get a fiddle or some html code to because only with css it's going to be hard to reply.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that when using a 50% width or height for a HTML element it actually means 50% of its parents width or height, try setting a width or height for the parent elements.